# Would a Computer Configuration Group policy affect an OU with just users if linked to it?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy

Or vice versa, Would a User Configuration policy affect an OU with just computers?

Answer (score 0):

By effect do you mean will it be run? Yes. To actually do anything you may need to set up a [loopback policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978513.aspx) if you *want* it to take effect.

You can also disable the Computer or User part of the policy if you like.